# Is it possible to visually display rows horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I want to display a set of images that sit next to each other

```
   <table id="datatable" class="table table-colored table-info">
    <thead>
     <tr >
   <th>Product_Name</th>
   <th>Image</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php while ($players_list=m ysqli_fetch_array($players_fun)) { ?>
 <tr>
   <td>
   <?php echo $players_list[ 'product_name']; ?>
   </td>
   <td>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
  <img src=" <?php echo $players_list[ 'product_IMAGE']; ?>" >
   </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <?php }?>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

this is my table can i show 3-3 images on each row ?

Actually i wanted to take advantage of data table's searching and sorting features..

Comment: DataTables is whole lot more than simply *searching and sorting*, sometimes it is easier to implement searching and sorting than make DataTables do something it is not designed for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) or [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) to achieve this. I have tried using css grid, please find [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhingeorgejoseph/6phrg05n/2/)

```
.img-vertical {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); // sets the horizontal layout
    grid-gap: 1em;
    place-content: center;
}

.img-vertical img {
    max-width: 50px;
}

.img-horizontal {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr); // sets vertically
}
```

alternatively, the flex implementation is as below

```
.img-vertical {
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: column; // sets vertically
}

.img-vertical img {
    max-width: 50px;    
}

.img-horizontal {
    flex-flow: row; // sets the horizontal layout
}
```